# Elasticsearch + searckick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

How can we use SQL queries like `select` and `group` on `<Searchkick::Results:0x007fe289b02a20>`? I have a large dataset of cricket, and need to execute the SQL `select` query to get aggregated results. Its simplest use case would be: to search a player by name using searchkick, then count its total matches, scores, ball etc using SQL `select` and `group`.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use SearchKick for aggregations like this

```
Player.search query, where: {name: params[:name]}, aggs: [:scores, :ball]
```

you may need to add `balls` and `scores` in players search_data if these are assosiations and not attributes of player's model.