# Group a Searchkick result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a basic Searchkick system set-up.  I want to take the results and then group them by an attribute to sum a another attribute etc.

This question is close to my issue:

[Elasticsearch + searckick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50366049/elasticsearch-searckick)

and the only answer was to use aggregations.  I could do that but then I would be building an active record call for each of the agg keys returned.

Here is what I have so far:

```
BudgetItem.all.search("*", body_options: { aggs: { cbs_item_id: { terms: { field: "cbs_item_id" }, aggs: { "total": { "sum": { "field": "total"  } } } } } } )
```

which results in:

```
 "aggregations"=>{"cbs_item_id"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>5, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>2956.0}}, {"key"=>6, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>7734.0}}]}}}>
```

in my search_data I have a term 'cbs' which is a text value that relates to the 'cbs_item_id'.  I am looking for this result:

```
"aggregations"=>
  {"cbs_item_id"=>
     {"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>
     [{"key"=>5, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>2956.0}, "cbs"=>{"value"=>"MY CBS Related Field" }},
      {"key"=>6, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>7734.0}, "cbs"=>{"value"=>"MY OTHER CBS Related Field" }}]}}}
```

This of this where you have in inventory of cars and a separate table of car_colors ( [id = 1, color = red], [id = 3, color = blue ].  I want to search for the cars of a given color then group them and sum etc.

I am sure I am perhaps missing something simple here.

**UPDATE**

Getting close:

```
BudgetItem.all.search("*", body_options: { aggs: { cbs_item_id: { terms: { field: "cbs_item_id" }, aggs: { cbs: { terms: { field: "cbs" } }, "total": { "sum": { "field": "total"  } } } } } } )
```

which results:

```
  "buckets"=>
    [{"key"=>5, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>2956.0}, "cbs"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"001", "doc_count"=>2}]}},
     {"key"=>6, "doc_count"=>2, "total"=>{"value"=>7734.0}, "cbs"=>{"doc_count_error_upper_bound"=>0, "sum_other_doc_count"=>0, "buckets"=>[{"key"=>"002", "doc_count"=>2}]}}]}}
```

The second "key"s 001 and 002 are the data I am looking for.